# Ffmpeg Split, transcode and concat results in audio out of sync

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video

I'm trying to convert a VFR or CFR .webm file into a .mp4. For doing so, I'm splitting the original video, then I transcode all segments (changing the fps), and after I concat the resulting transcoded segments. To test the result I play the .mp4 video without seeking, from start to finish, but after playing the video for some time, the audio and video start to slowly get out of sync. This is not happening when I seek across the video file. I'm testing this with different kinds of input files (VFR or CRF) and video formats (H264, VP9) and I'm getting the same result.

These are the steps involved in the process.

1. Segment Input

```
ffmpeg -i input.webm -c copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_list -segment_time 30 -segment_format matroska -vsync 2 -fflags +genpts %3d.webm
```

2. Transcode each segment

```
ffmpeg -i 000.webm -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -vf fps=fps=23.976 -movflags +faststart 000-out.webm
```

3. Concat

```
ffmpeg -y -loglevel debug -f concat -safe 0 -i files.txt -c:v copy -c:a aac -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

I noticed that if I add the following flag to the concat step the video and audio are in sync but at the expense of slightly changing the pitch at the joints.

`-af aresample=async=250`

```
[concat @ 0x7fba3680a200] file:1 stream:0 pts:167 pts_time:0.167 dts:NOPTS dts_time:NOPTS -> pts:31142 pts_time:31.142 dts:NOPTS dts_time:NOPTS
[concat @ 0x7fba3680a200] file:1 stream:0 pts:83 pts_time:0.083 dts:0 dts_time:0 -> pts:31058 pts_time:31.058 dts:30975 dts_time:30.975
[concat @ 0x7fba3680a200] file:1 stream:1 pts:11 pts_time:0.011 dts:11 dts_time:0.011 -> pts:30986 pts_time:30.986 dts:30986 dts_time:30.986
[Parsed_aresample_0 @ 0x7fba56505e00] [SWR @ 0x7fba40008000] compensating audio timestamp drift:0.010590 compensation:250 in:44100
[Parsed_aresample_0 @ 0x7fba56505e00] [SWR @ 0x7fba40008000] Using fltp internally between filters
[concat @ 0x7fba3680a200] file:1 stream:1 pts:35 pts_time:0.035 dts:35 dts_time:0.035 -> pts:31010 pts_time:31.01 dts:31010 dts_time:31.01
```

I have also noticed that v stream duration before and after the transcode step are slightly different. Also, if I copy the video stream instead of transcoding it in step 2, the problem still persists but not when I convert the full video without segmenting it.

I would like to know if it's possible to reencode the video without this audio drift happening and, if not, the reason behind that and/or an alternative approach. Thank you!

Comment: What is the reason for segmenting? Why not just do `ffmpeg -i input.webm  -movflags +faststart output.mp4`?

Comment: I am trying to do it in parallel to reduce overall transcoding times and apply filters faster. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to toss some stuff to you. It may help (or not).

Better than fps=fps=23.976 is fps=fps=24000/1001. This will give you a better timebase within the processsing stream. However, the matroska encoder will assert a 1KHz timebase, so it may make no difference.

When I know that an original video was CFR (BD and DVD movies), what I do to avoid timebase issues is to create my own timebase that generates solely integer PTSs (presentation time stamps) as follows:

-vf "settb=expr=24000/1001,setpts=expr=N"

(I do that in lieu of 'fps=', which I've found to be unreliable.)

That generates PTSs: 1 2 3 ... (in other words, each frame number, N, becomes that frame's PTS). That way, there's no rounding (or truncation) issues like there is with a 1KHz timebase.

In my applications, I take 23.976fps and convert it to exactly 24fps. Then I use motion vector interpolation to quintuple the framerate to 120fps. That displays really well on both 60Hz and 120Hz TVs, with zero telecine judder, and at the same rate (and running time) seen in theaters. I use 'atempo=1.001' to speed up the audio slightly to keep it in sync with the video. (Note that when fed 120fps video, 60Hz TVs simply drop every other frame, which is fine and is way better than telecine).

I don't know whether any of that will help you, but there ya' are. Good luck.